# Matlab Plot Differential of 8 mean curves

Tags: matlab, plot, differential-equations

I have one matrix with `8` instances of `1000` rounds with `1000` iterations in each one. Use a rand value`matrix=rand(8,1000,1000)` but in my case its date of time in miliseconds (0,003).

I want plot the one differencial curve of this `8` instances, note that is needed obtained the mean with `1000` rounds. So this one curve could represent mean value between `8` indexes of matrix.

Comment: What about it "doesnot work well" ?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you want to plot. Your title and code says "diff" but your explanation asks for one curve that represents the mean of the values at each index.

Comment: I removed this part because it's confused like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Plotting the mean of ALL rounds and ALL instances

```
plot(mean(matrix(1:8,:),2));
```

[image: plot]

`diff()` determines a derivative across a dimension (point-to-point subtractions); it does not sound like that's the function you should be using.

Comment: It's absolutely right. Thanks, it's simple but works.